# Searching a multidimensional array

Tags: python, search, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a small simulation which takes 3 input values, runs 100 random realisations and finds the mean and standard deviation of 5 output measurements.

The inputs and outputs I need to store somehow, and in a way that is easy to search for and plot/analyse the outputs for different sets of input parameters.

I currently have a big 23 * (number of input parameter combinations) array and try to search for, say, the mean of the first output parameter using
    `mean_of_a = data[3][[data[0]==x] and [data[1]==y] and [data[2]==z]]`

It doesn't seem to be working and I'm sure there must be a more efficient way of doing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: could you include a simplified version of the list you want to search? I think I can solve this with recursion but I'm a little confused to what you are working with

Comment: (1) I agree with the above comment.
(2) You realize that data[0]=x is an assignment statement ? what are you trying to do there?

Comment: Is it necessary to keep it only using `numpy`? I think this is the sort of thing that [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is really good for.

Comment: @Tomer, sorry, that's just a typo in the question, I obviously meant == which is testing for equality. I'll edit the question now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your matrix is `(parameters, repetitions)`, there are a few things wrong with your boolean indexing in its current form:

- `data[0]=x` assigns the value of `x` to `data[0]`. To test equality you need to use `==`.
- Square brackets are used to construct lists or for indexing into the previous variable. You need to use round brackets around your comparisons.
- For numpy arrays you need to use bitwise and (`&`) rather than `and`, which is only valid for scalars.

You want something more like this:

```
mean_of_a = data[3][(data[0] == x) & (data[1] == y) & (data[2] == z)].mean()
```

---

With numpy arrays it's more efficient to do all of your indexing in one go rather than "chaining" your indexing operations.

```
(data[0] == x) & (data[1] == y) & (data[2] == z)
```

should return a boolean vector whose length is the same as the number of columns in `data`. You can therefore use it to index directly into the second dimension of `data`, rather than indexing the 4th row first:

```
mean_of_a = data[3, (data[0] == x) & (data[1] == y) & (data[2] == z)].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have a problem with managing structured data. This seems like a good use case for `namedtuple`, which is a simpler version of a class.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Input = namedtuple('Input', ['x', 'y', 'z'])
Output = namedtuple('Output', ['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5'])

results = []

for i in range(100):
    input = Input(x, y, z)
    # do your thing
    output = Output(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5)
    results.append((input, output))
```

Now you have a list of input/output pairings. You can iterate, and access these members using dot notation.

For example - assuming you use `numpy`:

```
import numpy
print 'v1 mean', numpy.mean([r[1].v1 for r in results])
print 'v2 mean', numpy.mean([r[1].v2 for r in results])
```